# Xcode8 automatic code signing fails with DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-25295

Tags: xcode, keychain, provisioning-profile, xcode8, codesign

Im trying to use automatic code signing with Xcode8. However this fails with error DVTSecErrorDomain Code=-25295 "The specified keychain is not a valid keychain file."

[image: here is also an image of the status]

A similar issue existed with Xcode7, where I finally managed the certificates myself in the . Since Xcode8 gives a more specific error code, I am now wondering if anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to change `bundle identifier` and retry.

Comment: unfortunately no luck

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6702407)

Comment: thanks, this lead me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by creating a new "loginn" keychain and making this the new default keychain. (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702393/mac-os-x-keychain-access-a-default-keychain-could-not-be-found-error/6702407#6702407))

This fixes the issue but rises new problems with the whole system e.g random apps asking for passwords again, git push not working etc. This is not a good solution